# Select first item of MongoDB matching conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My app takes screenshots of webpages at various sizes on a daily basis. The pages and screensizes are set in jobs. Each job specifies an array of pages to capture, and a list of screensizes at which to capture each of those pages.

Whenever the app boots up though it automatically takes all screenshots for each active job again, just in case it hasn't taken the day's screenshots yet. This means that you can end up with a bunch of screenshots for the same job, page and screensize twice or more in the same day.

When viewing the screenshots though I only want to return a maximum of one shot with the same `job`, `page`, and `screensize` properties per day. To do this I want to build a query that will run through each day and check if that day has more than one shot. If it does, only return the one with the earliest `dateTaken` property.

I'm not sure if I should be using `$group` for this or not. I tried a few different queries with `$group` but it either combined all shots into a single result, or just returned all screenshots regardless of day taken.

Here's the screenshot schema:

```
const ScreenshotSchema = new Schema({
    job: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Job',
        required: true
    },
    dateTaken: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    page: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Page',
        required: true
    },
    screensize: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Screensize',
        required: true
    }
});
```

In short, what I need is: one item per unique combination of **job**, **page**, **screensize** and **day**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think grouping is the right approach: one takes the latest shot for each group. This can be achieved by using a descending `$sort` before `$group`, then picking the latest shot with the `$first` operator:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$sort" : { "dateTaken" : -1 }
    },
    {
      "$group" : {
        "_id": {
          job:"$job",
          page: "$page",
          screensize: "$screensize",
          year: { "$year" : "$dateTaken"},
          month: { "$month" : "$dateTaken" },
          dayOfMonth: { "$dayOfMonth" : "$dateTaken"}
        },
        "shot": { "$first" : "$$ROOT" }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it does result in unique values by screensize, page and job, but it only returns one result for each unique combination, whereas I need one *per day* per unique combination.

Comment: Hi Aron, I have added grouping keys to group further by day.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! Now is there any way of cleaning things up so that I just get a list of Screenshot documents (like you'd get from `.find({})`?). I'd rather not have to add post-processing to get rid of the documents wrapping the `shot` objects

Comment: The documents can be unwrapped by appending something like `.map(function(doc) { return doc.shot; } )`, which will return an array of all screenshots.

Comment: Mm yeah I think I'll do that. I just thought if there was something like that I could do within the query. In any case thanks for all your help!!